# Regex help substring

Tags: regex, perl

The following code used to work:

```
 my $matchExpr = "User created at \(UserIndex\) UserId = ";
 my @indexLine = grep /\Q$machExpr/, <LOGFILE>;
 ...
 my $indexId = $indexLine[0];
 $indexId =~ s/\Q$matchExpr//;
 chomp $indexId;
```

with a LOGFILE containing the line:

```
"User created at UserIndex UserId = "
```

However, the LOGFILE format changed to this:

```
"2017-01-01 08:50:22 User created at UserIndex UserId ="
```

and the code won't work anymore. Looking for a quick fix as no one here knows Perl.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$indexId =~ s/\Q$matchExpr//;
```

with

```
$indexId =~ s/^.*?\Q$matchExpr//;
```

Or replace the entire thing with the following:

```
my ($indexId) = grep /User created at \(UserIndex\) UserId = (.*)/, <LOGFILE>;
```